# Sequences proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Here's the question: $(s_n)$ and $(t_n)$ are sequences such that $|s_n| \leq t_n \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, and lim $t_n = 0$. Prove that lim $s_n = 0$

Here's my attempt at a proof. Can someone please verify it or offer suggestions for improvement?

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since lim $t_n = 0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n > N$, $|t_n| < \epsilon$.

Since $t_n \geq |s_n| \geq 0$, $|t_n| = t_n$.

Therefore, $\forall n > N$, $|s_n| \leq t_n < \epsilon$.

Hence, $\forall n > N$, $|s_n - 0| < \epsilon$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: I'm not sure there's even anything to offer you for improvement.  Was there something you were looking for specifically or felt uncomfortable about?

Comment: Why not use Squeeze Theorem instead?